# Building a function to get the product category ID of a product ID in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am trying to get the product category id of a product in WooCommerce. I am using the **WP All import-export plugin** where I can write my custom function. In the custom function having the product id or name I want to query it's **`category id`**.

Inside the theme’s functions.php file I can add a function like below and get the category id from the product id:

```
function my_get_category_id_from_product_id($product_id) {

    // do something to find the category to which my product belongs to and return it.

    return $category_id;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you post the code which you tried to achieve this ?

Comment: Inside the theme’s functions.php file I can add a function like below and get the category id from the product id:

function my_get_category_id_from_product_id($product_id) {
    // do something to find the category to which my product belongs to and return it.
    
    return $category_id;
}

Answer (score 3):

There is not always **just one category** for a product in WooCommerce. You can have also multiple categories for a product ID. Here is a function that will return the category Id of a given product ID in a **string**, but if multiple categories for this given product ID it will return a coma separate string of all categories ID for this product.

Here is the code:

```
function get_my_prod_cat_ids($prod_id) {

    $terms = get_the_terms( $prod_id, 'product_cat' );
    if($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            $cats_ids_array[$key] = $term->term_id;

            //To get only the first category (uncomment below)
            //break;
        }
        // to get an array replace below by: $output = $cats_ids_array;
        $output = implode( ",", $cats_ids_array ); 
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

**This code is tested and working.**

*Naturally this code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or in any plugin file.*